# Play Framework: use h2 database for development and postgresql in production mode and how to connect to the postgresql via conf-file

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, dockerfile, dev-to-production

I have the following prod.conf, containing the relevant information on how to connect to my PostgresSql DB.

```
slick.dbs.default {
  profile = "slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
  db.dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
  db.numThreads = 8
  maxConnections = 8
  driver="slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
  db.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
  url="jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/db"
  user="user"
  password="password"
}
```

(excerpt)

My Dockerfile looks like this

```
#...
RUN sbt stage

RUN cd target/universal/stage/bin

ENTRYPOINT ["target/universal/stage/bin/newsapi", "-Dplay.http.secret.key=KEY -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf"]
```

(excerpt)

With the `-Dconfig.resource=prod.conf` the application should start using the `prod.conf` and not the `application.conf`, right?

But when the application gets deployed it still uses a h2 database which is not part of the `prod.conf` and configured in the `application.conf`.

I dont get any warnings that the `prod.conf` could not be found/loaded or that the connection to the db could not be established.

What is the right way to solve this issue and is my db-url correct?

As a bit of context the postgresql db runs as a docker image as well as the play-applications. Bot are in the same network.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using different databases for development and production. Postgres has a lot of functionality that H2 doesn't cover, and it's very easy to programmatically spawn a Postgres container for testing purposes when the application starts. Take a look at this: https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/postgres/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Dconfig.resource` flag needs to be passed to the JVM, but you are passing it to your application instead.

If you're using sbt-native-packager (which Play uses by default), you should be able to pass the flag to the JVM by prefixing it with -J. So you need to pass `-J-Dconfig.resource=prod.conf`.

Here is the relevant documentation:
https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_app/customize.html#via-build-sbt

By the way, there is also a Docker plugin for sbt-native-packager.
https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html
I recommend you use it instead of writing Dockerfiles manually.